# Conditionally wrap error message in jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need to wrap an error message only if a certain condition is true. This means I can't use the wrapper property since it would always wrap the error message. So I'm using `errorPlacement()` with the following code.

```
    errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
        if (condition == true) {
            error.wrap("<li></li>").appendTo(element);
        }
        else {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Somehow this code doesn't have the message wrapped. First, am I right to replace `errorPlacement()` to get what I want done? Second, what am I doing wrong to wrap the HTML text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$('<li></li>').append(error).appendTo(element);`

Comment: Thanks! Just curious though, any idea what's wrong with error.wrap()? It is consistent with jQuery site examples.

Comment: @Tom, nothing is wrong with it, the only problem is that the return value is still the error object. Alternatively you could have done `error.wrap('<li></li>').parent().append(element)`